# useImperativeHandle hook does not update the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useImperativeHandle hook in my app to give access of value to the parent component:

```
const [phone,setPhone]=useState("");
 useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      type: "text",
      name: "phone",
      value: phone
    }),
    [phone]
  );
```

When I update phone using setPhone, value not going to be updated. What is the problem with my implementation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

useImperativeHandle needs to have the component use `forwardRef`, Once you do that, you will be able to access the updated ref in the parent since you are providing `phone` as a dependency to it.

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useImperativeHandle,
  forwardRef,
  useRef
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      type: "text",
      name: "phone",
      value: phone
    }),
    [phone]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPhone("9898098909");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
});

const Parent = () => {
  const appRef = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(appRef.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <App ref={appRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-surf-s4g81)

Comment: My component has forwardRef from its parent. As you I have passed ref to useImperativeHandle.

Comment: Yep, same setup, no avail.

Comment: no avail. must be some other issue

Answer (score 4):

If you're lazy and/or optimization isn't super important in your application yet, you can pass the dependencies of `[{}]` to `useImperativeHandle()` to update every time your component re-renders, ensuring that the values are always up-to-date.

```
const App = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      type: "text",
      name: "phone",
      value: phone,
      // other values that you don't have to keep track of via dependency list
    }),
    [{}]
  );
```

Comment: Or, don't provide any dependency at all, which does the same thing but without creating 2 empty unused values, e.g. `useImperativeHandle(ref, () => { ... });`

Comment: The proper solution is to put `phone` in the dependencies list right?

Comment: @KevinGhadyani yes